# C++ variadic templates with tuples

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

I want to write a function to extract some data from a binary buffer (assume the data is sequentially stored). The function returns data and the pointer after the extracted data, like this

```
std::tuple<const unsigned char *, int, double, float> data = Extract<int, double, float>(p_buffer);
```

which extracts an `int`, a `double` and a `float` number from `p_buffer`, and the first value of `data` indicates where to begin the next extraction work.

I tried to write something like this.

```
#include <tuple>

typedef unsigned char byte;

template<class TFirst, class... TRest>
struct Extractor
{
  static std::tuple<const byte *, TFirst, TRest...> Extract(const byte *p_current)
  {
    TFirst first_value;
    TRest... rest_values; // Not working.

    std::tie(p_current, first_value) = Extractor<TFirst>::Extract(p_current);
    std::tie(p_current, rest_values...) = Extractor<TRest...>::Extract(p_current);

    return std::make_tuple(p_current, first_value, rest_values...);
  }
};

template<class T>
struct Extractor<T>
{
  static std::tuple<const byte *, T> Extract(const byte *p_current)
  {
    return std::make_tuple(p_current + sizeof(T), *reinterpret_cast<const T *>(p_current));
  }
};
```

It doesn't compile because "parameter pack cannot be expanded in this context". I hear that function templates can't be partially specialized, so I use structs. How to make it work?

Comment: Please don't say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Make the return value a named type of a `char*` followed by a tuple, not one big tuple.  Or a two layer tuple.  Make similar changes elsewhere to keep types in tuples esp packs.  And should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pure C++11 solution:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

typedef unsigned char byte;

template <class Type>
void ExtractValue(const byte*& p_current, Type& value)
{
    value = *reinterpret_cast<const Type*>(p_current);
    p_current += sizeof(Type);
}

template <size_t index, class... Types>
typename std::enable_if<index == sizeof...(Types)>::type
ExtractImpl(const byte*& p_current, std::tuple<Types...>& values)
{}

template <size_t index, class... Types>
typename std::enable_if<(index < sizeof...(Types))>::type
ExtractImpl(const byte*& p_current, std::tuple<Types...>& values)
{
    ExtractValue(p_current, std::get<index>(values));
    ExtractImpl<index + 1>(p_current, values);
}

template <class... Types>
std::tuple<Types...> Extract(const byte *p_current)
{
    std::tuple<Types...> values;

    ExtractImpl<0>(p_current, values);

    return values;
}
```

This solution does not add `p_current` to the returned tuple, but you may easily fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I find it much simpler to go like this, with no template recursion at all ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a1aaf8e337d5cd6)):

```
template<typename T>
T extract(const byte *&p_current)
{
   const byte *p = p_current;
   p_current += sizeof(T);
   return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(p);
}

template<typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> Extract(const byte *&p_current)
{
   return std::tuple<T...>{extract<T>(p_current)...};
}
```

Unfortunately, due to a persisting [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253), gcc evaluates arguments of the `tuple`'s list-initialization in the opposite order (right-to-left), so you'll see in the live example that it works correctly only in clang. But it's still possible to apply this solution if one flips parameter list `T...` before calling `Extract`, just for gcc. I prefer to keep it simple and wait until the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
TRest... rest_values; // Not working.
```

This is not valid, you can't declare a variable of type `TRest...` because that's not a type (it's a pack of types).

Yakk's comment above is a cleaner solution, but if you really want to only use tuples you can do:

```
std::tuple<TRest...> rest_values;
```

and then modify the following code to work with that.

You cannot easily use `std::tie` with the tuple elements (you would need C++14's `apply()` function) so I would do this instead:

```
  static std::tuple<const byte *, TFirst, TRest...> Extract(const byte *p_current)
  {
    TFirst first_value;
    std::tuple<const char*&, TRest...> rest_values{ p_current, TRest{}... };

    std::tie(p_current, first_value) = Extractor<TFirst>::Extract(p_current);
    rest_values = Extractor<TRest...>::Extract(p_current);

    return std::make_tuple(p_current, first_value, cdr(rest_values));
  }
```

Where `cdr()` is the Lisp CDR operation, which returns everything but the first element of a list.

Comment: Lisp? Who said 'Lisp'?

Comment: @Constructor, I did. [Look it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR), it's a well-known function

Comment: It's a well known function, but it is not a C++ function.

Comment: @Constructor, but it's easy to write it, so I'm not going to bother doing it here. My answer explains the compiler error in the question, if you don't like the proposed alternative suggest something better.

Comment: In C++ you can not convert a tuple to an argument list simply.

Comment: Maybe you can't, but [I can](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3915.pdf)

Comment: I posted my variant. I don't know is it better or not, but it is a pure C++11 solution.

Comment: @Constructor, it's entirely possible in C++11, e.g. https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/source/HEAD:integer_seq_util.h

Comment: I know that it is possible, I just claimed that such conversion is not a simple operation in C++11.